# Let $X$ be compact, and $Y$ be $T_B$ space.Let $f : X ‎\longrightarrow Y$ be continuous map. If $X$ is Hausdorff, then $Y$ is also Hausdorff

Tags: general-topology

A topological space is called $T_B$ if every compact subset is closed.

Let $X$ be compact, and $Y$ be $T_B$ space.Let  $f : X ‎\longrightarrow Y$ be continuous map. **If  $X$ is Hausdorff, then $Y$ is also Hausdorff**.

But my question is that : **" is the   the surjective condition  necessary to proof " ? why?**

Comment: If $f$ is a constant map, then it will say nothing about $Y$. So some assumption is necessary.

Comment: @Daniel: A $T_B$ space is one in which every compact set is closed; such spaces are now more often called $KC$ spaces.

Comment: @Brian Thanks. Have you perchance any idea where the name $T_B$ space comes from?

Comment: @Daniel: It may have been Bill Fleissner’s term, first used in [this paper](http://projecteuclid.org/euclid.rmjm/1250128845); every $T_2$ space is $T_B$, and every $T_B$ space is $T_1$, so he thought of this as a separation property and gave it a $T$ name on that account. I don’t know why he (if he was indeed the first to use it) chose $B$ for the subscript, though.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott "Let us call spaces in which all compact sets are closed $T_B$ spaces, as this notion can be thought of as a separation axiom between $T_1$ and $T_2$. They are also called KC spaces." Bang on, thanks a ton. (Okay, it might still be that he was not the first to use $T_B$.)

Comment: @Daniel: He is, however, almost certainly the only person to name a space *George* (in ‘A collectionwise Hausdorff, not collectionwise normal space’, Gen. Top. Appl. $\mathbf{6}$ ($1976*), $57$-$64$)!

Answer (score 2):

Of course surjectivity is necessary. Let $Z$ be any compact $T_B$ space that is not Hausdorff, let $X$ be a compact Hausdorff space, and let $Y$ be the disjoint union of $X$ and $Z$. Let $f:X\to Y$ be the obvious embedding of $X$ into $Y$; then $f$ is continuous, but $Z$ is not Hausdorff.

Comment: what do these mean" Y be the **disjoint union** of X and Z" and "f:X→Y be the obvious **embedding** of X into Y"? why did you write $Z$?

Comment: @Alireza: Let $\langle X,\tau_X\rangle$ and $\langle Z,\tau_Z\rangle$ be spaces such that $X\cap Z=\varnothing$. Their disjoint union is the space whose underlying set is $Y=X\cup Z$, and whose topology has $\tau_X\cup\tau_Z$ as a base. In other words, a set $U\subseteq Y$ is open in $Y$ iff $U\cap X$ is open in $X$ **and** $U\cap Z$ is open in $Z$. The obvious embedding of $X$ into $Y$ is the identity map on $X$: $X$ is a subspace of $Y$. The point is that even though $f[X]$ is Hausdorff, $Y$ is not, because it has the non-Hausdorff subspace $Z$.